# iPhone AdHoc app - get rid of the badge

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uilocalnotification, badge

I have a tester which complains that after an update via iTunes, the app icon shows a red circle with #1 in to right corner and he could not get rid of it. He told me that he has deleted it, turned out the phone, installed it again, but that badge is there. I must mention that the app has a local notification when it got killed by the OS (appWillTerminate method) telling the user he should restart the app(is a location tracking app), but i think now is not the case, because the notification shows an alert too with a message.

Could someone telling me how he can get rid of that badge?

Thanks,

Alex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the app is re-launched are you resetting the badge?

To remove the badge you need to reset it yourself.  So in applicationDidFinishLaunching you could do the following to clear the badge:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber:0];
```